# A question about creating temporary functions in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a very basic C++ question. But I didn't find an appropriate answer after my own search. I saw some C++ code written like this:

```cpp
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b){return a[0] < b[0];});
```

1. `a` is a variable of type `vector<vector<int>>`.
2. `a[i][0]` means the key of the `i`th element
3. the purpose of those code is to sort `a`by key
4. So we need to pass a self defined compare function when calling "sort()"
5. the self defined compare function is defined by these codes:

   ```cpp
   [](auto &a,auto &b){return a[0] < b[0];}
   ```

I've never seen this way of writing (just like a lambda function in C++!), could you tell me how to understand these code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what part you don't understand? In addition to the code, you supplied a list that describes what it does. It's not clear which parts you understand or don't understand. That _is_ a lambda function (except there's a missing space between `return` and `a[0]`

Comment: It **is** a lambda function in C++.

Comment: I think op's having a problem sorting a 2D array? OP's probably not sure how to compare two vectors rather than integers. I'm only guessing because OP mentions a[i][0] as the element.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to re-use the name `a`. You should either rename your vector-of-vectors or rename the first parameter to the lambda you describe as "just like a lambda function in C++!"

Answer (score 0):

As per your question:

```
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b){return a[0] < b[0];});
```

`a.begin()[First], a.end()[Last]` - range of elements to sort

for the 3rd parameter, there are two options:

1. Lambda expression

   ```
    [](auto &x, auto &x){return x[0] < y[0];}
   ```
2. Comparison function

   ```
    bool comp(vector<int>& x, vector<int>& y) {
        return x[0] < y[0];
    }

    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comp);
   ```

> `a` is a `vector<vector<int>>`
>
> `x` and `y` are elements of `a` i.e. `vector<int>`
>
> Tip: **To avoid confusion, don't re-use the name `a` in the lambda expression(like I used `x` and `y` to avoid confusion)**
>
> The lambda expression or the comparison function takes a **pair of elements** from `a` and sorts them based on the first value(`x[0]`) of each element in `a`.
>
> If you see, both are very similar.
>
> a. Both accept an argument list. (`x and y` in this case)
>
> b. Both have a body `return x[0] < y[0];`

I hope this answers all of your questions.